# работа с динамической памятью - C (СИ)

Tags: c, строки, указатели

Здравствуйте, отправляю задачу на сервер, пишут:"Утечки памяти". Для входных данных: 3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *fibstr(int n) {
    int i=0;
    char *s1;
    char *s2;
    int len1=1;
    int len2=1;
    int sum=0;
    char *s=(char*)calloc(2,sizeof(char));
    char *s3;
    if(n==1) {
        strcpy(s,"a");
        return s;
    }
    if(n==2) {
        strcpy(s,"b");
        return s;
    }
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++) {
        sum=len1+len2;
        len1=len2;
        len2=sum;
    }
    s1 = (char*)calloc(sum,sizeof(char));
    s2 = (char*)calloc(sum,sizeof(char));
    s3 = (char*)calloc(sum,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s1,"a");
    strcpy(s2,"b");
    for(i=2; i<n; i++) {
        strcpy(s3,strcat(s1,s2));
        strcpy(s1,s2);
        strcpy(s2,s3);
    }
    free(s1),free(s2);
    return s3;
}

int main() {
    int n=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char *s=fibstr(n);
    printf("%s",s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите правильно очистить память.

Comment: Сколько раз у вас выделяется память и сколько освобождается?

Comment: выделил s1,s2,s3, освободил s1 и s2

Comment: выделили 4 раза освободили 2 раза

Comment: объясните как освободить память переменной, которую возвращаешь

Comment: @MeloDy. ну раз выделено больше чем освобождено - будет утечка.

Comment: @MeloDy. в Си (но не С++), можно писать просто `char *s1 = calloc(sum, sizeof(char));` поскольку эта функция возвращает указатель на `void *` то преобразование типов будет выполнено автоматически. Кроме того, если вы ориентируетесь на современный стандарт, то совершенно нет никакой необходимости объявлять переменные предварительно, в начале функции. Объявляйте их по мере необходимости. Код будет проще и понятнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> объясните как освободить память переменной, которую возвращаешь

Точно так же, как и любую другую, здесь у вас всё правильно. Ошибка в другом:

```
char *s=(char*)calloc(2,sizeof(char));
char *s3;
if(n==1) {
    strcpy(s,"a");
    return s;
}
if(n==2) {
    strcpy(s,"b");
    return s;
}
/* при n не равном 1 или 2 (как в вашем случае!) попадаем
   сюда, и память, выделенная для s, не освобождается */
```

Comment: Блин, спасибо большое. исправил, записав это в главной функции без массива.

Answer (score 0):

В самом начале функции вы выделяете память, адрес которой заносите в переменную `s`

```
char *s=(char*)calloc(2,sizeof(char));
```

Однако если `n` больше `2`, то эта память в функции не освобождается.

Кроме того, вы недостаточно выделяете память для строк. Рассмотрите пример, когда `n` равно `3`. В этом случае `sum` также будет равно `3`. Однако в `s3` вы в итоге заносите строку `"bab"`, которая содержит `4` символа, включая завершающий символ `'\0'`, а память  была выделена только для 3 символов. В результате программа имеет неопределенное поведение..

Comment: освободил s, и добавил это:

Comment: s1 = (char*)malloc((sum+1)*sizeof(char));
  s2 = (char*)malloc((sum+1)*sizeof(char));
  s3 = (char*)malloc((sum+1)*sizeof(char));

Comment: @MeloDy. Да,  надо учитывать завершающий 0 строк. В самом начале у вас len1 и len2 равно 1. Однако вы правильно выделяете память равную 2. Однако когда n больше 2, вы забыли про завершающий 0.:)

Comment: спасибо, разобрался :)